# create button wordpress admin didn't work

Tags: wordpress, admin

I tried to create a button on wordpress admin(post.php) with input by user.
When i add for example "**1x312**" and click on button need to open a new page with youtube.com/embed/**1x312**

I create button into functions.php with this code:

```
add_action('media_buttons', 'add_my_media_button');
function add_my_media_button(){
 echo '<a target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/embed/'.$variale.'" class="button button-default">Click here to view</a>';
 echo '<input type="text">';
}
```

When i type into input field how to add into my function?

```
<?php $variable = <input type="text"> ?> - how to do that?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a form here and then ajax that will send the form input to the function that will it.

Smth like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="post" class="custom-button">
        <div class="form__body">
            <div class="form__row">
                <label for="field-userinput" class="form__label">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Some Label Here', 'default' ); ?>
                </label>

                <div class="form__controls">
                    <input type="text" class="field" name="field-userinput" id="field-userinput" value="">
                    <span class="span-error"><?php esc_html_e( 'This field is required.', 'default' ); ?></span>
                </div><!-- /.form__controls -->
            </div><!-- /.form__row -->
        </div><!-- /.form__body -->

        <div class="form__actions">
            <button class="form__btn btn" type="submit">
                <?php esc_html_e( 'Submit', 'default' ); ?>
            </button>
        </div><!-- /.form__actions -->
    </form>
```

And then the ajax:

```
$( 'form.custom-button' ).on( 'submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $( this );

    // validations here

    if ( form.find( '.error' ).length === 0 ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: siteUrl.ajax_url + '?action=custom_button',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                // do smth on success
            }
        } );
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

after that is the wordpress:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_button', 'custom_button' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_button', 'custom_button' );

function custom_button() {
 // here at the $_POST you will have the input and can make whatever you like with it
}
```